# JavaScript countdown to MySQL datetime format

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, countdown

I have a date that comes from a MySQL database in the `datetime` format, something like `2010-09-24 11:30:12`. And I need a way to show a countdown of hours:mins to that date.

I'm not very familiar with dates in JavaScript so any help would be apreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function in MySQL to return your date in [Unix Time Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (the number of seconds since January 1, 1970). Let's say our target date is `'2011-01-01 00:00:00'` (in reality you would probably have a field from your table, instead of a constant):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2011-01-01 00:00:00') AS timestamp;
+---------------+
| timestamp     |
+---------------+
| 1293836400    |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then we can use the [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method of the `Date` object in JavaScript to calculate the number of seconds between the current time and the target time. Once we have the number of seconds, we can easily calculate the hours, minutes and days:

```
var target = 1293836400;    // We got this from MySQL
var now = new Date();       // The current tume

var seconds_remaining = target - (now.getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0);
var minutes_remaining = seconds_remaining / 60;
var hours_remaining = minutes_remaining / 60;
var days_remaining = hours_remaining / 24;

alert(seconds_remaining + ' seconds');     // 8422281 seconds
alert(minutes_remaining + ' minutes');     // 140371.35 minutes
alert(hours_remaining + ' hours');         // 2339.5225 hours
alert(days_remaining + ' days');           // 97.48010416666666 days
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery plugin http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Just pass your mysql date and time to js as js variable

syntax is

```
$(selector).countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HMS'})
```

js code here

```
 function mysqlTimeStampToDate(timestamp) {
    //function parses mysql datetime string and returns javascript Date object
    //input has to be in this format: 2010-09-24 11:30:12
    var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;
    var parts=timestamp.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6").split(' ');
    return new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],parts[3],parts[4],parts[5]);
  }
$('#selector').countdown({until: mysqlTimeStampToDate(<? echo "2010-09-24 11:30:12" ?>), format: 'HMS'});
```

Comment: well, that looks easy. but im not using jquery but prototype, so that would add a few issues to the page and also a few extra kb's just for this little thing. thanks anyway.

Comment: check the updated code again, its ready to use. Based on "jquery" though

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Date.parse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) method that might work.